# SharePoint Online Powershell CSOM create list from custom template

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

All,

I am trying to create a list using a custom list template that includes content for SharePoint Online using powershell and CSOM.  The list template for now is already loaded into the site collection.  If I go through the UI, I can create the list on a site using the template including content without issue.   If I try to do it through powershell, the list gets created but without the columns and or contents.

```
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green 
} 
$web = $clientContext.Web
$templates = $clientContext.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
$clientContext.Load($templates)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$template = $templates | Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq "SomeTemplate" }

$lci = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$lci.Title = "Some List"
$lci.TemplateFeatureId = $template.FeatureId
$lci.TemplateType = $template.ListTemplateTypeKind
$lci.DocumentTemplateType = $template.ListTemplateTypeKind

$lists = $clientContext.Web.Lists;
$clientContext.Load($lists);
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

$list = $lists.Add($lci)
$list.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

I can't figure out what is missing, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to associate Fields to Content Type (CT) and then add this CT to your List.

Try look at this:

http://www.sharepointfire.com/2016/01/create-new-content-type-sharepoint-online-powershell/

In previous step he created Columns(Fields) which he used in creation:
$columns = "BlogNumber", "BlogText", "BlogUser"

Hope it will help you.
Alex

Comment: Also pretty helpfull article and mainly module for SP Online operations like this:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Module-for-5ecbbcf0#content

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have to add the list template before update. It works for me

```
...      
$lci.Title = "Some List"
$lci.TemplateFeatureId = $template.FeatureId    
$lci.TemplateType = $template.ListTemplateTypeKind    
$lci.DocumentTemplateType = $template.ListTemplateTypeKind   
$lci.ListTemplate = $template   
...
```